Salesforce Apex Access Nested Lists after Parsing JSON with Wrapper Class
I think I am just missing something simple - using very simplified and generic code for example.
I have some JSON:
{
   "level1":[
      {
         "level2":{
            "id":119,
            "createdAt":"2024-05-06T17:36:32.533Z",
            "user":{
               "id":1,
               "firstName":"First",
               "lastName":"Name",
               "email":"firstName@none.com",
               "emailUnsubscribed":"false"
            },
            "organization":"Acme",
            "details":[
               {
                  "d1":{
                     "ref":"ref1",
                     "name":"BetterName",
                     "moreDetails":[
                        {
                           "detail1":{
                              "name":"smith",
                              "random":"123123123"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "d1":{
                     "ref":"reg2",
                     "name":"Name2",
                     "moreDetails":[
                        {
                           "detail1":{
                              "name":"ccg",
                              "random":"333444555"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "detail1":{
                              "name":"acg",
                              "random":"555666777"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}

That I use a Wrapper class to parse:
public class fromJSON{
    public cls_level1[] level1;
    class cls_level1 {
        public cls_level2 level2;
    }
    class cls_level2 {
        public Integer id;  
        public String createdAt;    
        public cls_user user;
        public String organization; 
        public cls_details[] details;
    }
    class cls_user {
        public Integer id;  
        public String firstName;    
        public String lastName; 
        public String email;    
        public String emailUnsubscribed;    
    }
    class cls_details {
        public cls_d1 d1;
    }
    class cls_d1 {
        public String ref;  
        public String name; 
        public cls_moreDetails[] moreDetails;
    }
    class cls_moreDetails {
        public cls_detail1 detail1;
    }
    class cls_detail1 {
        public String name; 
        public String random;   
    }
    public static fromJSON parse(String json){
        return (fromJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(json, fromJSON.class);
    }

}

But when I do something like:
fromJSON testWrapper = fromJSON.parse(json);
System.debug(testWrapper.level1);
|DEBUG|(cls_level1:[level2=cls_level2:[createdAt=2024-05-06T17:36:32.533Z, details=(cls_details:[d1=cls_d1:[moreDetails=(cls_moreDetails:[detail1=cls_detail1:[name=smith, random=123123123]]), name=BetterName, ref=ref1]], cls_details:[d1=cls_d1:[moreDetails=(cls_moreDetails:[detail1=cls



I can see the data, but cannot access it.
System.debug(testWrapper.level1.level2)
Variable does not exist: level2

Not sure what I am missing or forgetting.
Thanks in Advance!

testwrapper.level1 is a list, rather than a single instance. The List type itself doesn't have a level2 variable (as the error states).
So you need to iterate over the list to get at a single instance, from which you would be able to access level2.
// <OuterClass.InnerClass> needs to be used to reference inner classes
//   outside of the class that contains it (the inner class)
for(fromJSON.cls_level1 level1Instance : testWrapper.level1) {
    system.debug(level1Instance.level2);
}


Ugh, I new I was missing something simple. THANK YOU!

And if I wanted to get to say the details in level2? Nested For loops do not seem like a good idea for this, maybe I need to change everything into Maps?

Nested loops are an inevitability when you have nested collections (sets, maps, or lists). Nested loops aren't inherently evil, it's mostly just stuff of the form if(loop1Var.fieldA == loop2Var.fieldA) that you need to watch out for.

Thank you again!!
